# Use IF in a mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` where I need to select a specified table by a column wich define the type of subject:

```
table_buildings
id      name                location      source_type      source_id
1       NY Appartament      New York      0                NULL
2       Guggenheim  Museum  Manhattan     1                27
3       MoMA                New York      2                3

table_url // source type == 1
id      name               url
27      Guggenheim  Site   http://www.guggenheim.org/

table_books // source type == 2
id      name               pages           sample         author
3       World Museums      125-127         path/img.jpg   John Smith
```

I don't know if it's possible, but I have some problem to solve it without an `IF` statement inside my query because I can find the right table by the `source_type` column of `table_buildings`

does exist soma tecnique to use an `IF` inside a `SELECT` query?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you expect for a result based on the data provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just join both tables and use `COALESCE` for duplicate column names in the joined tables.

```
SELECT COALESCE(table_url.name, table_books.name) as name, url, pages, sample author FROM table_buildings
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_url ON table_buildings.source_type = 1 AND table_buildings.source_id = table_url.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_books ON table_buildings.source_type = 2 AND table_buildings.source_id = table_books .id
```

Comment: I've found it very easy to use! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the only possible way is select from all tables unconditionally. Not a much overhead though.
Just left join as much tables as you need. ones with no corresponding information will just return nulls.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll remember it, I thought something like this because of performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could `UNION` three different `SELECT`s that `JOIN` to the three tables with `WHERE` clauses.

Alternatively, you could join against all three tables in one query and use a `CASE` operator to select a column from the appropiate joined table based on `source_type`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "CASE WHEN" in the SELECT.

```
SELECT
 table_buildings.id,
 table_buildings.name,
 table_buildings.location,
 CASE WHEN table_buildings.source_type = 0
  THEN ""
  ELSE CASE WHEN table_buildings.source_type = 1
   THEN table_url.name
   ELSE table_books.name
   END CASE
  END CASE AS source_name
FROM table_buildings
LEFT JOIN table_url
ON table_buildings.source_id = table_url.id
LEFT JOIN table_books
ON table_buildings.source_id = table_books.id
```